# Deploy additional jars to repo using maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, clojure, maven-release-plugin

I'm using [zi](https://github.com/pallet/zi) and [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) to generate jar files which I'm attempting to submit to the maven central repo. One of the requirements for inclusion in the central repo is that the artifact have a -javadoc.jar file that contains the generated javadocs. If that's not possible they [require](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Central+Sync+Requirements) that you have an empty -javadoc.jar file in order to pass the automated tests.

I'm generating the empty jar file using [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and I'm placing it in the correct location, but it's being ignored by maven-release-plugin. As a result it's not being signed by my GPG key and it's not being deployed to the repo.

Is it possible to generate an empty javadoc jar file using the javadoc plugin?

If the javadoc plugin won't generate an empty jar file how do I get the maven-release-plugin to recognize, sign and deploy the jar file which is being generated by my shell script?

Is there some other option that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. Instead of creating the empty jar file via the shell script directly you need to create target/apidocs using the exec-maven-plugin plugin as part of the compile phase.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Generate Empty Javadoc</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>${basedir}/scripts/emtpy-apidocs.sh</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>${project.build.directory}/apidocs</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then during package phase you use the javadoc plugin to create the jar. The resulting jar will now be picked up by the release plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-javadocs</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to add the jar-source via the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) which can be used attach artifacts to the cycles.

Answer (score 1):

are you using clojure to write a maven plugin or creating a project written in Clojure?

clojure-maven is a tool for writing maven plugins using clojure:

```
Maven components to allow the use of clojure when writing maven plugins.
```

If you are creating a project in Clojure, the [zi plugin](http://palletops.com/zi-the-maven-plugin-in-clojure/) which was designed for creating clojure projects that are compatible with central, may be what you are after.  It's written by the same author (Hugo Duncan).

Comment: You're right about zi, I'm actually using it as well, long day.. Question is updated. +1 for you.

Comment: hugo hangs out on #pallet on irc.freenode.net and is very responsive in fixing/improvingthis sort of thing.